# Is there any library to recognize date in any format?

Tags: javascript, php, date, datetime

Is there any external or native library that would recognize inputs like examples below and return some universal datetime format:

"`friday`" - returns datetime of closest friday to current day in future.

"`18:00`" / "`18h`" / "`6pm`" / "`6p.m`" / "`6 p.m`" - returns datetime of 18 today if its before 18 or 18 tommorrow if its after 18 today

etc etc. like `Decempber 5th` , `December`

I'm going to create my own library like that, but before I've made some research to find out if there is something like that already so I'll not have to re-invent wheel. I could not find anything like that.

It could be in any language, but I would strongly prefer web-languages like `javascript` / `php`.

Comment: You should take a look at date.js and moment.js, both come with some very handy functions.

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at 'strtotime()' ?

http://php.net/strtotime